# Exporting GeoJSON from PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson, ogr2ogr

I am, trying to export GeoJSON from postgis. I am using the following code which is working local machine but when I am trying to use this in a server the following error is occuring

CODE:

> ogr2ogr -progress -f GeoJSON landuse_gen0.geojson -t_srs EPSG:4326 
>   "PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=database user=usernbame
>   password=Password"  -sql "SELECT way, way_area AS area,
>   COALESCE(landuse, leisure, 'natural', highway, amenity, tourism) AS
>   type  FROM planet_osm_polygon  WHERE way_area > 100000  ORDER BY
>   way_area DESC"

ERROR:

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `PG:host=localhost port=5432 dbname=database user=usernbame password=Password' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `PDF'
  -> `ESRI Shapefile'
  -> `MapInfo File'
  -> `UK .NTF'
  -> `OGR_SDTS'
  -> `S57'
  -> `DGN'
  -> `OGR_VRT'
  -> `REC'
  -> `Memory'
  -> `BNA'
  -> `CSV'
  -> `GML'
  -> `GPX'
  -> `KML'
  -> `GeoJSON'
  -> `ESRIJSON'
  -> `TopoJSON'
  -> `OGR_GMT'
  -> `WAsP'
  -> `OpenFileGDB'
  -> `XPlane'
  -> `DXF'
  -> `CAD'
  -> `Geoconcept'
  -> `GeoRSS'
  -> `GPSTrackMaker'
  -> `PGDUMP'
  -> `GPSBabel'
  -> `SUA'
  -> `OpenAir'
  -> `OGR_PDS'
  -> `HTF'
  -> `AeronavFAA'
  -> `EDIGEO'
  -> `SVG'
  -> `Idrisi'
  -> `ARCGEN'
  -> `SEGUKOOA'
  -> `SEGY'
  -> `ODS'
  -> `XLSX'
  -> `SXF'
  -> `Selafin'
  -> `JML'
  -> `VDV'
  -> `MVT'
  -> `TIGER'
  -> `AVCBin'
  -> `AVCE00'
```

Comment: Can you connect to the database using some other means, such as psql? Is is possible that you are trying to connect on an Internet socket, while the DB server is only listening on a Unix domain socket?

Comment: ST_AsGeoJSON works as well https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the version of `ogr2ogr` you have on server was built without PostgreSQL support, or the postgres driver is not installed. Note that in the list of drivers there is no PostgreSQL, `ogr2ogr` just tries all existing drivers and none of them understands the connection string - this is what the error message means.

`ogrinfo` might provide better diagnostics.